# Will saving information in files instead of mysql queries help performance and save resources?

Tags: mysql, optimization

Is it a good practice to save mysql queries' information into .html files and show those files instead of executing mysql queries each time? It will save bandwidth, I guess, but it will take much more space resources, right? Maybe there is another better way to avoid to execute mysql queries?

Answer (score 1):

in place of storing them into .html file. Use memcache 
http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php